Quarto document not seeing project directory for targets data, functions, or scripts
I've used R Markdowns within targets pipelines for a while and I'm trying to move over to Quarto documents, however I'm having a number of issues with the transition.

source() no longer seems to see my project directory
tar_load() cannot find the _targets folder with the saved/completed targets
tar_source() no longer loads in my functions.

Example file structure:
$
│ test_proj.Rproj
| packages.R
│
├─-data
│    mtcars.csv
├─-R
|    testing123.R
└─-docs
     quarto.qmd
     markdown.rmd


source()
In .Rmd documents, I was easily able to use source("packages.R") to source a script where I have all of my library calls in one place e.g.

library(tidyverse)
library(here)
library(targets)

In the markdown.rmd, I'm able to use source("packages.r") and call this script when I'm knitting, with the markdown using my project directory by default. In the quarto.qmd, the same code gives me the Error in `file()`:! cannot open the connection when I try to render it. Updating this code to
library(here)
source(here::here("packages.R))

allows me to render the quarto doc, but it feels like this should be necessary given I'm already working within the context of a project.

tar_load() anywhere in the quarto doc gives me Error:! targets data store _targets not found. Utility functions like tar_read() and tar_load() require a pre-existing targets data store, which leads me to believe that the quarto doc cant see the _targets folder in the main project directory.

tar_source() assumes that the folder directory for user-defined functions is "R", which is where I keep all of my functions. Again, the quarto doc doesnt seem to know what my project directory is, so tar_source() cannot find my functions. I need to amend the code to be tar_source(files = here::here("R")), which shouldnt be necessary because I'm working in a project.


Its my understanding that all of these things would be solved if I could make the .qmd work out of my project directory, as the .rmd is able to.
Does anyone have advice for working with .qmd and NOT having to put everything into the same folder as the .qmd? That seems like a horrible way to organize data and functions, especially in a project, and most especially when working with the Targets package.
